# How do I tell if player (white cube) is inside a valid position (transparent cubes) in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

[image]

The player is a white cube. I can move the player. The player let say moves one cube unit at a time. I have 8 transparent cubes here which are the possible positions the player can be in. Of course, I will add more transparent cubes later. If the player is not inside a transparent cube he falls or hits a wall or whatnot.

I need help starting. I was thinking putting all the transparent cubes inside a list then in Update function I can compare the player's position with all the transparent cube's position. I do not want to hard code it like this:

```
if (transform.position.x < 0 || transform.position.x > 4) {
    DoSomething();
}
```

because it does not help in other scenarios.

Comment: I'm not sure this question really falls under the umbrella of stack overflow. If you want to do something and you have an idea of how you want to do it, then you should try your idea (which sounds reasonable enough to me) and come back if it doesn't work out.

Comment: It sounds like you need to read up on Colliders. https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CollidersOverview.html

Comment: Thanks. I know a little about collider. Should help me even if plane is not simple design. I was hoping someone would give me code instead.

Comment: I don't think that's the point of Stack Overflow. There are plenty of code examples on the Unity documentation, like this: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnTriggerEnter.html

Answer (score 0):

Give all transparent boxes a `BoxCollider` and enable `IsTrigger`

You could e.g. use a certain [`tag`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Tags.html) to identify the cubes and a list of Colliders.

If you enter a trigger you add one, if you leave atrigger you remove one.

If the list is empty you are not touching any trigger and fall

```
// in the inspector here you set the target tag 
// the player should collide with
[SerializeField] private string _collideWithTag;

private List<Collider> _colliders;

private void Update()
{
    if(_colliders.Count > 0) return;

    // not in a valid area -> fall or whatever
}

private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if(other.gameObject.tag != _collideWithTag) return;

    if(_colliders.Contains(other)) return;

    _colliders.Add(other);
}

private void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
{
    if(other.gameObject.tag != _collideWithTag) return;

    if(!_colliders.Contains(other)) return;

    _colliders.Remove(other);
}


// the above should be enough but you could go sure and also use
private void OnTriggerStay(Collider other)
{
    if(other.gameObject.tag != _collideWithTag) return;

    if(_colliders.Contains(other)) return;

    _colliders.Add(other);
}
```